# Is it possible to view user wise usage statistics in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use firebase realtime database in an application.

The whole realtime database size is about 250KB. But, in certain days, I can see that the download volume of realtime database goes for about 250MB, which is usually about 5MB in other days.

I need to find out the reason for these download peaks. Is there any way I can isolate a user, or a database path which contributes to the data downloads from realtime database?

Answer (score 1):

At this level of granularity you can use **Stackdriver Monitoring** to see individual performance metrics.

> With Stackdriver Monitoring from Google Cloud Platform, you can use
>   the Metrics Explorer to see individual performance metrics, or create
>   different dashboards with charts that display various combinations of
>   performance metrics over time. The Realtime Database integration with
>   Stackdriver Monitoring offers the deepest level of granularity.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/monitor-performance#stackdriver-monitoring

Stackdriver Monitoring is available at https://app.google.stackdriver.com/. You can create custom charts from firebase metrics, which are listed here https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-firebasedatabase

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could find to discover more details about the issue was using the [firebase profiler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile).

```
firebase database:profile --project <my_project_id>
```

It showed the database paths which were accessed during the profiling, including the number of bytes downloaded. It didn't show which user accessed the database, but the database rules of my database allow users only to access db path allocated to them, so the user information could be derived by looking at the database paths.